# How to find the list of only application running in windows?

Tags: java, windows, process

I want  to find the list of all  application running in windows.The list should consist of application only and not all process

`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec
        (System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");
        try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line); //<-- Parse data here.
            }
        }`

Comment: ...stuff that you tried that did not work and would like to share?

Comment: I used "tasklist" command but it gives me list of all background process that are not useful to me.I am developing an application in which user can get what application are currently running by them only.

Comment: share java code in your question so, people would see that you actually tried something before asking and you will not get your question downvoted

Comment: @aviad shared the code

Comment: what's wrong with that code ? doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

An **application** is a **program which you interact with on the desktop**. This is what you spend almost all of your time using on the computer. Internet explorer, microsoft word, iTunes, skype - they are all applications.

A **process** is an **instance of a particular executable** (`.exe` program file) running. A given application may have several processes running simultaneously. For example, some modern browsers such as google chrome run several processes at once, with each tab actually being a separate instance/process of the same executable.

So, what you could do is:

```
try {
        String line;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");
        BufferedReader input =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            //<-- Parse the line and insert into a set using image field as a key
        }
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    } // do not forget to handle exceptions!
```

you will need some filtering though, for example inserting the result of the tasklist command into a Set by the name in the 'image' column because they are all associated with the same app:

[image]

Comment: I already found out that answer in some other previous  stackoverflow question.Can you give me more information about dome filtering?btw it is windows 7.